# SSRS report finding longest duration of computer idle time

Tags: datetime, reporting-services

I have a report I've created using SSRS. It currently is pulling the Date and Time for the last input received on a computer. My goal is to find the longest time a computer was idle. I have the data but just need to figure out how to logically extract it.

Here is a screenshot of example data: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRFs4.png)

Based off of this I would be able to say that the longest time duration that the computer has been idle would be 3 days on the 19th. Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Below is my query for my original dataset:

```
Select 
  a.Name0 AS [Computer Name],
  b.LastKeyInput0 AS [Last Input Time]
From
  v_R_System a
    Inner Join
  v_HS_UHHG640 b
on b.ResourceID = a.ResourceID
where a.Name0 = @ComputerName
```

This query will return a computer and history of it's idle times as linked below:

[Query Designer Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlPjn.png)

Question: How do I tie in your solution with this query? THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've replicated your data for this example. I'm not sure what you want in your final output but this will give you enough to go on. This answer is rather long winded as I've tried to explain each step. Ultimately you could remove half the code but building it bit by bit helps understanding.
If you want to just look at the final query, go to the bit labelled "Finally:" below

To create your data I simple did the following

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(LastInputTime datetime)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('2020-09-18 11:13'),
('2020-09-19 12:58'),
('2020-09-19 12:58'),
('2020-09-19 12:58'),
('2020-09-22 11:32'),
('2020-09-23 10:12'),
('2020-09-24 11:51')
```

Next we can show this data and the previous rows data using the LAG function.

```
SELECT 
    *
    , PreviousDateTime = LAG(LastInputTime, 1, LastInputTime) OVER(ORDER BY LastInputTime)
FROM @t
```

The `LAG()` function here gets the LastInputTime column from the row that is LAG 1 (the previous row). If not row is found, the 3rd argument says, return the current row's value instead. This default just makes the next bit cleaner.

We get the following results
[image]
As you can see the PreviousDateTime shows the previous row (except on the first row where no previous row exists).

Now we have the previous row's data, we can use it to calculate the time between the two values with

```
IdleTimeInSeconds = DATEDIFF(s, LAG(LastInputTime, 1, LastInputTime) OVER(ORDER BY LastInputTime), LastInputTime)
```

Here we use `DATEDIFF()` and get the number of seconds (`s`), from the PreviousDateTime (out lag function), to the LastInputDateTime.

So our query now looks like this...

```
SELECT 
    *
    , PreviousDateTime = LAG(LastInputTime, 1, LastInputTime) OVER(ORDER BY LastInputTime)
    , IdleTimeInSeconds = DATEDIFF(s, LAG(LastInputTime, 1, LastInputTime) OVER(ORDER BY LastInputTime), LastInputTime)
FROM @t
```

And gives this result.
[image]

Keeping it simple, we can now use this as a subquery and get the top 1 row ordered by IdleTimeInSeconds in descending order. We can wrap the result in a bit of text so it makes more sense in a report.

---

**Finally:**

This is the final query which you can run to test as it requires no actual data

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(LastInputTime datetime)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('2020-09-18 11:13'),
('2020-09-19 12:58'),
('2020-09-19 12:58'),
('2020-09-19 12:58'),
('2020-09-22 11:32'),
('2020-09-23 10:12'),
('2020-09-24 11:51')

SELECT top 1 
        *
        , Message = 'Longest idle time was '
            + CAST(IdleTimeInSeconds as varchar(20))
            + ' seconds, from '
            + CAST(LAG(LastInputTime, 1, LastInputTime) OVER(ORDER BY LastInputTime) as varchar(20))
            + ' to '
            + CAST(LastInputTime as varchar(20))

    FROM (
        SELECT 
            *
            , PreviousDateTime = LAG(LastInputTime, 1, LastInputTime) OVER(ORDER BY LastInputTime)
            , IdleTimeInSeconds = DATEDIFF(s, LAG(LastInputTime, 1, LastInputTime) OVER(ORDER BY LastInputTime), LastInputTime)
        FROM @t
    ) x ORDER BY IdleTimeInSeconds DESC
```

This gives the following result.

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

Based on you supplied query, the final query will look like this...

```
SELECT TOP 1 
        *
        , Message = 'Longest idle time was '
            + CAST(IdleTimeInSeconds as varchar(20))
            + ' seconds, from '
            + CAST(LAG([Last Input Time], 1, [Last Input Time]) OVER(ORDER BY [Last Input Time]) as varchar(20))
            + ' to '
            + CAST([Last Input Time] as varchar(20))
    FROM (
          SELECT
            a.Name0 AS [Computer Name],
            b.LastKeyInput0 AS [Last Input Time],
            PreviousDateTime = LAG(b.LastKeyInput0, 1, b.LastKeyInput0) OVER(ORDER BY b.LastKeyInput0),
            , IdleTimeInSeconds = DATEDIFF(s, LAG(b.LastKeyInput0, 1, b.LastKeyInput0) OVER(ORDER BY b.LastKeyInput0), b.LastKeyInput0)
          FROM v_R_System a
              JOIN v_HS_UHHG640 b on b.ResourceID = a.ResourceID
          WHERE a.Name0 = @ComputerName
         ) x ORDER BY IdleTimeInSeconds DESC
```

Comment: This is well written and works beautifully! Thank you so much! The only issue I am having now is pulling my data from the SSRS tablix into the table you are declaring in your code. Would I create a second dataset for this or add it into the original dataset query somehow? Again.. thank you!

Comment: It depends on what your current dataset query looks like. You should be able to integrate your code into the method I described. Update you question and show your current query and I will try to help.

Comment: I have updated the original question with explanation and query. THANK YOU!

Comment: I've updated the answer to include you original code, you'll see there's not much of a change required, just adding the couple of calculated columns and changing a few column names. If this answers your question , please  mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.